# Laravel 5.2: asset path not working on server

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

My laravel 5.2 app unable to fetch the stylesheet from the public/css directory on the production server but can fetch stylesheets on the local machine!

here is how I am linking my files:

```
<link href="{{asset('css/clock.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
```

I also tried bunch of different ways:

```
<link href="{{URL::asset('css/clock.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
```

OR:

```
{{HTML::style('css/clock.css')}}
```

but nothing worked on server!

but it is not able to fetch the css! when I check the page source, it shows me some other css file linked.. is it because of '.htaccess' file that I used to redirect to the public folder of my site?

you can have a look at [enter link description here](http://mountsinaiindia.com)..

please help!

Comment: Please give information about your directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

Why are u not trying url helper like this

```
<link href="{{ url('css/clock.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
```

Note:- css/clock.css is in public folder

Comment: didn't work! works on local server but not on server! can .htaccess create a problem?

Comment: do u have ssl certificate if yes than use this

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

 # Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: which .htaccess file do i post this? one in public folder or the one in /www folder?

Comment: error: "the page i was looking for could not be found!"

Comment: what are u using dedicated or shared hosting

Comment: shared, It is actually forwarding me to a path to the public directory of my folder, which I had already done with other .htaccess file in /www folder

Answer (score 0):

The **asset()** helper prepends the base URL to the path you supply.
But laravel keep js, css, and image files into **public** folder so you need to add public path like this:

`href="public/{{ asset('css/style.css') }}.`

**Instead of doing this edit into this file:-** `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php`

```
function asset($path, $secure = null)
{
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='127.0.0.1:8000')
        return app('url')->asset($path, $secure);
    else
        return app('url')->asset('public/'.$path, $secure);
}
```