# laravel 5: external css won't import on shared hosting with SSL enabled

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

{I asked for this question before but didn't get a solution, so please try and understand..}

I am able to run my external javascript and css on my local machine, but I am unable to fetch the same on my shared hosting with go daddy (cannot afford dedicated)!

Although I could use the style and js if written internally...

I have tried a bunch of methods like:

```
<link href="{{asset('css/clock.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
```

OR:

```
<link href="{{URL::asset('css/clock.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
```

OR:

```
{{HTML::style('css/clock.css')}}
```

OR this one:

```
<link href="{{ url('css/clock.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
```

I installed laravel using this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HVJlAFBrafA), which included in making of one more .htaccess file in www folder.

so how do i tackle this? please help!

Comment: What do you mean by "external css." It's on your site, but you can't load the file? Do you get a 404 in the console? What does your htaccess file look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.2: asset path not working on server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38414746/laravel-5-2-asset-path-not-working-on-server)

Comment: If you have asked this question before, please go back and modify your previous question instead of asking a new one. Modifying a question will bring it back to the top of the recent list. Splitting comments and questions across multiple questions will make it harder for you to get a satisfactory response.

Comment: thanks all, i've had many non-helpfull answers on that link... so i wrote down the question again

Comment: Why not use site relative root paths? All the Laravel helpers will prefix with the HTTP path. Using plain old /css/clock.css should work regardless of shared hosting environment

Answer (score 0):

Your @include statements in your CSS files that reference external stylesheets are what's throwing the error.

Simply don't use @import statements without https:// URL's. If you have to, then use something like a `gulp task` to fetch those and compile for you on the server side (although I still don't like this, and think it better to use package management like npm or bower).

Answer (score 0):

If your domain is SSL protected your css and js has to be a "https".
To do so for external links(CDN links) make sure you are giving it like "https://link.com/test.css"..
And to add internal links from public folder

user

```
{{ asset('css/clock.css', true) }}
```

Here in asset true parameter adds https instead of http